# How to get HTTP POST data in AWS lambda via API Gateway using Python

Tags: python

Having an AWS lambda function (Python 3.6) triggered by API Gateway, I need to retrieve and process data from http request.

The lambda function will be trigger by an API Gateway, say https://aws-uri/some-api-gateway

e.g. POST with data 
param1: test
param2: test2

```
curl -X POST \
  https://aws-uri/some-api-gateway \
  -F param1=test \
  -F param2=test2
```

The lambda function will need to retrieve the HTTP POST data for further process.

param1: test
param2: test2

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # not sure if params should be retrieved from event,
    # or from http server
    print(event['param1'])
    print(event['param2'])
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('test!')
    }
```

What's the best practice to implement this lambda function?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: A simple hello world lambda script to get params from passed event arguement.

Comment: You can `print(event)` so you'll know how to get it.